# How to get value from the object but its type is unreachable

Tags: c#, reflection

For instance, in my current class, there is a hashtable,

```
Hashtable t = GetHashable(); //get from somewhere.

var b = t["key"];
```

the type of b is hidden from my current class, it is unreachable, not a public class type.

but i want to get a value from b,  for example b has a field call "ID",
i need to get the ID from b.

is there anyway i can get it, reflection ???

Comment: Re field vs property: a field is `public int Foo` - where a type exposes a variable **directly** (not recommend); a property is hidden behind accessor methods: `public int Foo {get;set;}` or `private int foo; public int Foo {get {return foo;} set {foo = value;}}`. Properties allow for validation, side-effects, notifications, abstraction, polymorphism, refactoring, etc - and pretty much have zero cost since simple properties are "inlined".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't know the type, then you'll need reflection:

```
object b = t["key"];
Type typeB = b.GetType();

// If ID is a property
object value = typeB.GetProperty("ID").GetValue(b, null);

// If ID is a field
object value = typeB.GetField("ID").GetValue(b);
```

Comment: (replied to that question on the top post)

Comment: how about the properties is sepcify as internal..your method didn`t work for it

Comment: If it's internal (or private/protected), use:  typeB.GetProperty("ID", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(b, null);   (For details, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103.aspx)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Thanks for replying before I saw the comment ;)

Answer (score 6):

In C# 4.0, this would just be:

```
dynamic b = t["key"];
dynamic id = b.ID; // or int if you expect int
```

Otherwise; reflection:

```
object b = t["key"];
// note I assume property here:
object id1 = b.GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetValue(b, null);
// or for a field:
object id2 = b.GetType().GetField("ID").GetValue(b);
```

Another easier approach is to have the type implement a common interface:

```
var b = (IFoo)t["key"];
var id = b.ID; // because ID defined on IFoo, which the object implements
```

Answer (score 0):

By unreachable, you mean not a publically instantiable type?  Cause if the assembly that defines this type is not there, then the object itself could not be fetched, the compiler would throw an error.

So, if the assembly defining the type is there, then yes you can use reflection to get at it...

Answer (score 0):

Just Try :

```
 DataSet ds = (DataSet)OBJ;

 Int32 MiD  = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MachineId"]);
```